# Visual Studio 2017 is missing Xamarin (packages)

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm quite desperately trying to make my Visual Studio working whit Xamarin.

I installed a complete new Visual Studio Community Edition with Mobile Development option.

Then I created a new Project as C# → Android-App (Xamarin).

When I open the solution it shows the following:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget; // .Support not available (gray)
using Android.Support.V4.View; // .Support not available (gray)
using Android.Support.V4.Widget; // .Support not available (gray)
using Android.Support.V7.App; // .Support not available (gray)
using Android.Views;
```

It seems I'm the only one on earth who has this problem.
In the NuGet manager there are no Xamarin packages listed.
The Android Support Repository v47 is installed in the SDK Manager.

Please help me out.

Comment: "In the NuGet manager there are no Xamarin packages listed." Show a screenshot please. Also show what are the NuGet feeds on your machine and if you are behind a proxy.

Comment: This is the screenshot. The NuGet ffeeds will follow.
https://ibb.co/n6jhy07
And more of the errors:
https://ibb.co/2P9bHMD

Comment: This happens when I try to manually install the package "Xamarin.Android.Support.v4"
https://ibb.co/NVRQczC

Comment: For some reason, your machine only enabled Visual Studio offline cache feed, which is impossible for VS to restore the necessary packages used in this project. You have to add nuget.org feed, or set up your own internal NuGet server to host the mandate packages.

Comment: Thank you so much.
It works now.
Why can't I upvote your comment and selct it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Copied from the comment.

For some reason, your machine only enabled Visual Studio offline cache feed, which is impossible for VS to restore the necessary packages used in this project. You have to add nuget.org feed, or set up your own internal NuGet server to host the mandate packages.